# Definition of pullback of a Weil divisor on an abelian variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

We are on an abelian variety, so Cartier divisors, Line bundles and Weil divisors are all equivalent. I would like to see the pullback of a Weil divisor. Is it true that, if $D=\sum n_i E_i$, then the pullback $\phi^* D$ is defined as $\sum n_i \phi^{-1}(E_i)$?

If not, how is it actually defined? And are there eventually special cases in which the above definition holds?

Thanks.

Comment: Why should $\phi^{-1}(E_i)$ have codimension 1? Why not take the pullback of the line bundle?

Comment: Because I want to see it in terms of Weil divisors. I know already how it looks like in terms of line bundles.

Comment: What is $\phi$?

Comment: A morphism whatsoever

Comment: A morphism from where to where?

Comment: Between two abelian varieties. I'm interested in two cases in particular: from X to X and from X to X/F, where $F\subset X$ is a closed subgroup. But maybe you can tell me particular cases in which we get an interesting result depending on the abelian varieties.

Comment: You are being too loose. Stating what you need more precisely can help avoid this back and forth. If $F$ is a finite group, what you say is correct. If not, inverse images of Weil divisors may not be one and so the map has to be defined only in terms of line bundles or after moving the divisor.

Comment: Well it's a surjective map, so one can pull back Cartier divisors by pulling back equations.

Comment: Yes F is a finite group!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pullback it's easily defined for Cartier divisors.

Let be $\varphi : X\longrightarrow Y$ a dominant morphism of suitable varieties. Then we can show that there exists a group morphism $\varphi^* : \operatorname{Div} Y \longrightarrow \operatorname {Div} X$. The dominant hypothesis is not necessary but I'll assume it for the sake of simplicity; recall that for such a morphism, there is a field immersion $\varphi^* :k(Y)\hookrightarrow k(X)$, where $k(-)$ denotes the field of rational functions.

First of all, you should know that a Cartier divisor $D$ over $Y$ can be represented by a couple $(\{U_i\}_{i\in I},\{f_i\})$ where $\{U_i\}$ is an open cover of $Y$ and $f_i$ is a rational non zero function over $Y$, such that $f_if_j^-1$ is a regular function **over** $U_i\cap U_j$, for all $i,j\in I$.

With such identification, we define 
$$\varphi^* D\in\operatorname{Div}(X)$$
by the means of the couple
$$(\{\varphi^{-1}(U_i)\}_{i\in I}, \{\varphi^* f_i\})$$
where $\varphi^*$ is the forementioned field extension.

It's straightforward to check that $\varphi^*D$ is a Cartier divisor.

Comment: What does "field immersion" mean in this context?

Comment: Just an injective map between two fields. Maybe it is more appropriate to say "field extension".